# SharePoint : Feature scope question

Tags: sharepoint

When I create my feature I have the following choices for feature scope:

- WEB
- SITE
- WEB APPLICATION
- FARM

Which is the correct scope to select if you want your feature to be available in :

```
Site Settings > Site Features
```

Might seem trivial but its driving me up the wall, thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be Web, using the SIte scope will make it available in the Site Collection features

Comment: Ah I see the problem... content types can't be installed at a Web Scope, only Site Scope +